# Converting CloudSQL instances from Public to Private IP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

Can't we convert a `CloudSQL` instance with `Public IP` to a `Private IP`. The `Private IP` is on `SharedVPC` allocated using `Private service Connection` .

It is failing for me with below error

```
   $ gcloud --project=<project id> beta sql instances patch test1-instance --network=https://www.googleapis.com/compute/alpha/projects/<SharedVPC Host Project>/global/networks/kube-shared-vpc                                                                                                                         
   The following message will be used for the patch API method.
   {"name": "test1-instance", "project": "<project-id>", "settings": {"ipConfiguration": {"privateNetwork": "https://www.googleapis.com/compute/alpha/projects/<SharedVPC Host Project>/global/networks/kube-shared-vpc"}}}

   ERROR: (gcloud.beta.sql.instances.patch) HTTPError 400: This operation is not valid for this instance.
```

It works if the `private IP` is on the same network of `CloudSQL instances` but when private IP is allocated from `SharedVPC` it is not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to enable [Private IP](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/private-ip) on existing Cloud SQL instance when trying to attach the instance to a Shared-VPC and there is [PIT](https://issuetracker.google.com/124070944) on this issue as Feature Request to enable that. The current workaround is to enable the Private IP on Cloud SQL instances at creation time.